# USB drive doesn't show up as sdb/sdc

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, usb, mount, dmesg

I was trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 with a Live USB drive and ran into some issues where I booted the USB drive and after choosing 'Start Ubuntu withouth installing' in grub it froze at the screen where the ubuntu logo with the white/orange dots shows up. I messed with some grub options (namely 'nomodeset' and 'acpi=off') and tried other images/burn methods/programs and still got the same issue. Now I'm at the point I think I messed too much with the USB drive because it doesn't show up as sdb/sdc/etc. anymore. I can't see it with gparted or `lsblk`.

`lsblk` output:

```
...
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   190M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0   1,9G  0 part /boot
├─sda3   8:3    0   9,2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda4   8:4    0  18,6G  0 part /
└─sda5   8:5    0 203,1G  0 part /home
```

when I connect the device and run `dmesg` though I get:

```
...
[  828.615759] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  842.945337] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  843.093594] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201
[  843.093597] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  843.094031] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  843.095254] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[  844.114362] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NAND     USB2DISK         
0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  844.115134] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  844.116132] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

What happens here?

Comment: The disk is now connected as `sdb`, as shown in the last line. It should be visible with `gparted`. There is a drop-down list in the upper right corner of the Gparted UI where you can select the device.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't though. As much as I understand the `dmesg` log it says that a USB drive gets recognized and gets bound to `sdb` but `lsblk` and software like `gparted` doesn't show it.

Comment: I have same issue with OTG usb flash device it's showup first time bu lather dissapear from storage list